# Dynamic form field extraction and calculation, how?

Tags: javascript, forms, field

I have a form with variable length of dynamic field names, for instanced, item{n}, the n could be 1 or 30, and I need to calculate the subtotal of qty{n} * price{n} for each such data row, then finally sum subtotal up.

The form looks like the following:

```
<form>
    <table name="forInstruction">
        <tr><td>... </td> <td>...</td> ... more td </tr>
        ....
    </table>

    <table name="forUserinput"> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="item1">,</td> <td><input type="text" id="qty1">,</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="price1">,</td> <td>fieldX1 t1 </td> ... more td
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="item2">,</td> <td><input type="text" id="qty2">,</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="price2">,</td> <td>fieldX2,t2 </td> ... more td
            <td><input type="text" id="item3">,</td> <td><input type="text" id="qty3">,</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="price3">,</td> <td>fieldX3,t3 </td> ... more td
            ... 
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate subtotal and total" ... /> 
</form>
```

Notes: 
a) t{n} = subtotal field. 
b) as mentioned above, number of rows is unknown, it could be 1 to 30. 
What I'd like to do is: calculate subtotal and total. 
each subtotal = qty{n} * parseFloat(price{n}) 
My attempt is to loop through the entire form, I'm able to retrieve 
all the values for the qty{n} field, 
but I don't know how to retrieve the value of its Corresponding 
Price{n}.

```
var fQ=0,fP=0; 
st = 0; 
total = 0; 
for (f=0; f < document.qr.elements.length; f++) { 
    if (document.qr.elements[f].name.indexOf('qty')>=0) { 
        // alert(document.qr.elements[f].name + ' ' + document.qr.elements[f].value); 
        fQ = document.qr.elements[f].value; 
        // alert(fQ); 
    } 
    else if (document.qr.elements[f].name.indexOf('priceLabel')>=0) { 
        fP = document.qr.elements[f].value; 
    } 
    // what do we do here?  Or this is not the good way to go? 
}
```

Maybe, loop through the entire form isn't a good idea... only data rows in a named table?  If so, how?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:
Upon advice,
new code:

```
 var i = 0, t=0,
      element; 
   while ((element = forms[0].elements['qty' + i])) {
     var subtotal = forms[0].elements['qty' + i] * forms[0].elements['price' + i]; 
         forms[0].elements['total' + i].value = subtotal;
         t = t + parseFloat(subtotal);
         alert(t);
     // ... 
     i++;
```

}

```
forms[0].elements['totalFinal'].value = t;
```

but err msg:
"ReferenceError: forms is not defined".  How come?  Thanks.

Comment: You could also give a specific common `name` to all the elements you want to operate with and get them with `getElementsByName`

Comment: Is a framework like jQuery an option or must it be straight Javascript?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, using the element seems the way to go. To MDJ, jQuery isn't being used for this app.  But, I'm receiving a form error.